# social network off-peak sharing

Tags: facebook, twitter, coldfusion, social-networking

My coldfusion app allows users to post a comment as with any typical blog. I want to give the users the option to autoshare their comments on their favourite social networking sites (at least Twitter). Ideally, I want to create something like [YouTube Account Sharing](http://www.youtube.com/account_sharing).

I've spent several hours looking at twitter documentation. I get how to set up a simple tweet button for real-time tweeting. But, if I wanted to run a scheduled task during off-peak times to upload subscribers' comments to their specified networks, surely this would require storing some type of twitter credentials for each user in a database for later authentication. If anyone has done something similar, I would appreciate a shove in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take a look a [OAuth for Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) and their REST API.

Essentially you will need to store Twitter access tokens with your application and use it to post tweets on behalf of a user, using [the REST API call](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update).

Hope that helps.